# Loop trough vector elements... and make new vector

Tags: r

I have this vector `X<-c("A","B","C")` and I need to create a new vector from `X` where elements are `newX <-c("A-B", "A-C", "B-C")`... I tried a series of nested `for` loops, but I can't figure it out.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no for-loops needed here.

```
sapply(combn(X, m = 2, simplify = FALSE), paste0, collapse = "-")
#"A-B" "A-C" "B-C"
```

Comment: Maybe a shorter one `combn(X,2,paste0,collapse = "-")`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding forgot all about the FUN-argument in combn... good find!